# Using Behaves_like<TBehavior> on a Base Class

Tags: c#, bdd, mspec

I would like to specify a Behaves_like on a base specification to ensure that a particular method is marked as virtual. Something like this:

```
public abstract class command_handler_context<TCommandHandler, TCommand> 
    : abstract_context<TCommandHandler>
    where TCommandHandler : ICommandHandler<TCommand>
    where TCommand : ICommand, new()
{
    protected static TCommand Command;
    private Establish context = () =>
    {
        Command = new TCommand();
    };
    private Because of = () => SubjectUnderTest.Execute(Command);

    private Behaves_like<ExecuteMethodOverridableBehavior<TCommandHandler>> an_overridable_execute_method;
}
```

However the test runner does not pick this up. I think it would be a major PITA to specify ehaves_like on every single spec for a command handler. Is this possible? If not, is this a desired behavior?

Update: Sorry about the late response, here is the failing spec:

```
public abstract class context_base
{
    protected static bool Result;
    protected static bool RanOnBaseClass;
    private Because of = () => { Result = true; };

    private It should_be_true = () =>
    {
        RanOnBaseClass = true;
        Result.ShouldBeTrue();
    };
}
public class when_using_behaviors_on_a_base_class
    : context_base
{
    private It should_run_specs_on_the_base_class = () => RanOnBaseClass.ShouldBeTrue();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Behaviors are currently only supported on context classes, not base classes. <strike>Would it be feasable to factor the `It`s of the `ExecuteMethodOverridableBehavior` behavior right into the base class? (`It`s in base classes will be executed when derived contexts execute.)</strike>

Sorry, I must have been out of my mind when writing the answer above. `It` fields are *not* supported on base classes, only `Establish` and `Because`. While there can be only one `Because`, there might be multiple `Establish` clauses in the hierarchy.

I fear putting the behavior (`Behaves_like`) on all derived classes is the only way to go.

Comment: I would prefer to do it that way. However it doesn't work. It doesn't show up in the resharper test runner, and it doesn't run from the command line.

Comment: Just to make sure I get this right: `It` fields in base classes do not work for you? Can you please post the complete code (including the behavior's specifications) somewhere?